# How to make second identical footnote on a page match existing one?

Tags: footnotes, context

In ConTeXt, one can use \footnote[someid]{my message} to place a footnote and \note[someid] to place another superscript number in the text, that will reference the same message, using the same number.

I have a macro like this:

```
\define\mymacro{#1 \footnote{#2}}
```

Here #1 is the word and #2 is the definition.

In a document, it looks like this:

```
There is an animal called the \mymacro{octopus}{sea animal with 8 legs} that lives in the ocean. The  \mymacro{octopus}{sea animal with 8 legs} likes to eat fish. Sometimes the \mymacro{octopus}{sea animal with 8 legs} will eat crabs.
```

This then places three identical footnotes on the page. How can I have only the first on the page only show a footnote, and the rest of the references point to that footnote, only allowing a new identical footnote to be made on the next page?

Comment: If this is for citations, then you should just use one of the footnote citation styles. If this is for something else, then it may be easier to (ab)use the citation tooling to do what you want. This shouldn't be too hard to implement from scratch either.